# Capture 108MP image on Samsung S22 Ultra with Camera2

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-camera2

How to capture 108mp images using Camera2API on Samsung S22 Ultra?

In the native camera it shows an option to capture 3:4 108MP images, but in Camera2, retrieving the available output sizes for different ImageFormat, the maximum resolution is 4000x3000.

How can I access the 108MP resolution (12000 x 9000) programmatically using Camera2API?

Comment: A question like this has been asked before and CommonsWare suggested that what was possible for a Samsung app developer could not be reachable for us.

Comment: Dear blackapps, Thank you for your reply. I am trying to find A way to get 108MP image. but it is very hard to find.